# How to read two files in node and check if the words exist in both

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying out new things in node, So here I want to read two files and check if all the words in the files are the same.

**Example**: Two similar files where one file has some extra words added to it.

So after checking both the files, if the words of one file don't exist in the other file, then those words should be printed out

Here is what I have tried so far, But this doesn't seem to work as expected and isn't the right way

```
let newData = [];
let oldData = [];

(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.readFile(
      pathname.join(__dirname, "public", "hello.txt"),
      (err, data) => {
        const wordsInFile = data.toString().toLowerCase();
        // Here we should split string by some delimiter for further words processing. Assume, that your file looks like this "word1 word2". We'll use space delimiter.
        newData = wordsInFile.split(" ");
        resolve();
      }
    );
  });

  // here is the same code for the second file. Or you can move code to another function.
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.readFile(pathname.join(__dirname, "public", "test.txt"), (err, data) => {
      const wordsInFile = data.toString().toLowerCase();
      // Here we should split string by some delimiter for further words processing. Assume, that your file looks like this "word1 word2". We'll use space delimiter.
      newData = wordsInFile.split(" ");
      resolve();
    });
  });
  // And now we can use Set from ES6, to find intersection/difference etc.
  const wordsNotInFileAndNotInFileTwo = new Set(
    [...newData].filter(x => !oldData.has(x))
  );
  console.log(wordsNotInFileAndNotInFileTwo);

  // But you can simple iterate two arrays to achieve your goal.
})();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: one way, you could nest your `readFile` and do the comparison inside the nested `readFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest `readFile`:

```
fs.readFile(pathname.join(__dirname, "public", "hello.txt"), (err, data) => {
  newData = data.toString().toLowerCase();
  fs.readFile(pathname.join(__dirname, "public", "test.txt"), (err, data) => {
    oldData = data.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (newData === oldData) {
      console.log("Same");
    } else {
      console.log("Not Same");
      const a = newData.split(' ')
      const b = oldData.split(' ')

      const result = a.filter(w => !oldData.includes(w));
      console.log(result.join(' '));
    }
  });
});
```

This way, callback in inner function has access to variables set in the outer function.

Comment: But this still doesn't show the word that isn't in the other file

Comment: `still doesn't show the word that isn't in the other file` what do you mean? do you get any error?

Comment: No error, It just prints out the entire words in the file rather than that specific word

Comment: because that's what your logging `oldData` is the entire string in `test.txt`

Comment: Yeah, So how do I print out the specific data?

Comment: That depends, is the *different* word at the end of the string or could be anywhere in between?

Comment: It could be anywhere

Comment: Like one files has "My name is xxx" and the other files has "My name is xxx and" , then the "and" should be printed

Comment: updated answer to fit what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You are a god !

Answer (score 0):

The first point is asynchronous behaviour of `fs.readFile` function.
In short, you have to `await` while each file would be read. Or, at least, one of files.
Here is example with [IIFE](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/), but you can use any asynchronous function or use promises.

```
let newData = [];
let oldData = [];

(async() => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.readFile(pathname.join(__dirname, "public", "hello.txt"), (err, data) => {
      const wordsInFile = data.toString().toLowerCase();
      // Here we should split string by some delimiter for further words processing. Assume, that your file looks like this "word1 word2". We'll use space delimiter.
      newData = wordsInFile.split(' ');
      resolve();
    })
  })

  // here is the same code for the second file. Or you can move code to another function.

  // And now we can use Set from ES6, to find intersection/difference etc.
  const wordsNotInFileAndNotInFileTwo = new Set([...newData].filter(x => !oldData.has(x)));
 // But you can simple iterate two arrays to achieve your goal.
})()
```

Here is nice article about [`Set`](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html).

**To sum up:**

First, you need to await while file would be read.
Second, you can find words difference via `Set`.

Comment: Sir, Why does wordsNotInFileAndNotInFileTwo  print no value ? I have updated the answer with the new code